# How do you merge untracked code with a tracked codebase?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have to deal with two code bases, let’s call them Base_A and Base_B for the same project where Base_B is a direct copy of Base_A.  *Both code bases will be actively developed.*  I will periodically receive a copy of Base_A and want to merge its changes with Base_B (which will be version controlled).

However, Base_A does not have any version control, and for various reasons I can’t bring it under version control.  I understand the problem with this but it is out of my control.

Is it possible to merge periodic changes and updates from Base_A into Base_B?    It doesn’t matter if I use Git or SVN.

Answer (score 3):

> *However, Base_A does not have any version control, and for various reasons I can’t bring it under version control. I understand the problem with this but it is out of my control.*

The pattern you're looking for here is a "vendor branch". That's where you have 3rd party code, like releases of 3rd party software. You create a branch to track their releases so you can merge them into your code.

Establish a branch like `vendor/Base_A`. As new versions of Base_A become available, commit them, unmodified, to this branch. `git add -A` makes this easy. Just drop the new version in the working directory (if it's in a zip or tarball, unpack it), `git add -A`, and commit.

Then merge or rebase `vendor/Base_A` and `Base_B` like any other branch.